# C# FormWindowState.Normal not to steal focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, windowstate

I have a Windows Form Application that will go to system tray when it is minimized. When I received a message to pop-up my application it will call ShowWindowFromTray() function. I do not want to steal focus on the application that has the focus because it might interrupts on what the user is doing.

```
private void ShowWindowFromTray()
{
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

BTW this application has option that the users can check if the application will always on top or TopMost on all other windows.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to display a [balloon tip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx) from your app's icon in the notification area? This is the standard way of showing non-obtrusive alerts/messages. (By the way, it's called the "notification area", not the "system tray". There is no such thing as a "system tray".)

Comment: we also have a balloon tip in the notification area. It is the user's preference, and choices will be made from the user depending on what he chooses on the preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Show(), use the ShowWindow() API with [SW_SHOWNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
    private const int SW_SHOWNA = 4;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    private void ShowWindowFromTray()
    {
        ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_SHOWNA);
    }
```

Comment: That's awesome. Very very minor nitpick: According to the MSDN you linked 4 is SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE, and 8 is SW_SHOWNA. I do get that they're very similar and both will work for Jeff's purposes.

Comment: Good spot...copying and pasting too quickly.  =O